# NHibernate Inheritance mapping when sub class in Separate Assembly

Tags: .net, nhibernate-mapping, subclass

Assume that the core project has a base entity and every plugin maybe extends the base entity.

Solution structure :

```
Application.Core.BaseClass
Application.Module.SubClass (it's a plug in, maybe not available)
```

Is any way to implement this mapping using NHibernate subclass?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a mapping with like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" xmlns=""urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
    <subclass name="SubClass" extends="BaseClass" discriminator-value="SubClass"/>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

And then

```
cfg.AddXml(xml);
```

You could take a look at code from a [project](http://code.google.com/p/n2cms/source/browse/trunk/src/N2/Persistence/NH/ConfigurationBuilder.cs) with similar goals.

There is also the option of directly invoking the class model.