# Nhibernate Mapping By Code - Extend Subclass

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate

In the following [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311318/nhibernate-inheritance-mapping-when-sub-class-in-separate-assemblly), the answer shows how to do an `extends="BaseClass"` in XML. How do I do the same thing in Mapping By Code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mapping by code will generate the serialized mappings when adding them to the configuration hence it doesn't need to specify extends explicitly.

Comment: Turns out my issue was related to something else and this was working correctly. Thanks.